# ASP.Net MVC Creating a register bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this thing running at my application.
I have 3 tables, 1 main table and 2 other tables that are needed to create the main table, the main table depends on the 2 tables, they are connected with constraints.
I have the main table: Word
Then I have the two other tables: Difficulties and Category.
I created the Difficulty: Easy and then I created the Category: Nature.
So now, I would be able to create as many words as I could with those 2 attributes, but it gives me an error.
I can only create a word if I create this way

> Dificulty -> Category -> Word

or

> Category -> Difficulty -> Word

.
I can't create a word without making that path and I don't know why.
The values are stored in a database that will be called in 2 ComboBoxes, 1 for the Difficulty and the other one for Category.
If I wanted to create a word I would need to create a new category and a new difficulty otherwise it will return as null.

This is my Model View:

```
public partial class palavra
    {
        public int id_pal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LETRAS { get; set; }
        public string PISTA { get; set; }
        public int id_cat { get; set; }
        public int id_dificuldade { get; set; }
        public string nomepalavra { get; set; }

        public virtual  categoria categoria { get; set; }
       public virtual dificuldade dificuldade { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var palavras = db.palavras.Include(p => p.categoria).Include(p => p.dificuldade);
           return View(palavras.ToList());
        }



        // GET: palavras/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.id_cat = new SelectList(db.categorias, "id_cat", "TIPO_CATEGORIA");
            ViewBag.id_dificuldade = new SelectList(db.dificuldades, "id_dificuldade", "TIPO_DIFICULDADE");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: palavras/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_pal,LETRAS,PISTA,id_cat,id_dificuldade,nomepalavra")] palavra palavra)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.palavras.Add(palavra);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.id_cat = new SelectList(db.categorias, "id_cat", "TIPO_CATEGORIA", palavra.id_cat);
            ViewBag.id_dificuldade = new SelectList(db.dificuldades, "id_dificuldade", "TIPO_DIFICULDADE", palavra.id_dificuldade);
            return View(palavra);
        }
```

This is my view:

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nomepalavra)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LETRAS)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PISTA)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.categoria.TIPO_CATEGORIA)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dificuldade.TIPO_DIFICULDADE)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomepalavra)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LETRAS)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PISTA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.categoria.TIPO_CATEGORIA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dificuldade.TIPO_DIFICULDADE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id_pal }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id_pal }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id_pal })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Whenever I run my code to insert I get this error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries.
>   See the inner exception for details.

When I check the Details it appears that the "Category" table and the "Difficulty" table are null but the others fields are all with the info that I gave them.

> My Database Schema is the following:
>
> Category connects to Word and Difficulty connects to Word.
>
> Both Category and Difficulty are a 1 to many relationship with the
>   table Word.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your HttpPost palavra action method and see you have alll the needed property values.

Answer (score 1):

if you are use entity framework you need to defined your constraint at your model there is 2 options, code first or database first

here my example with database first

[Database First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

after you generate your model from db, easy step to create create update delete with scaffolding

[Scaffolding crud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

with scaffolding you much easier to create crud, and if any constraint

example above you create work with selecting Difficulty / Category yes your dropdownlist will be created automatically

example my codes menu creator controller

```
   // GET: SystemMenus/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.SystemMenus, "Id", "Name");      
        ViewData["Color"] = new SelectList(OptionDropdown.GetBackgroundColor(), "Value", "Text");
        ViewData["Size"] = new SelectList(OptionDropdown.GetSize(), "Value", "Text");
        ViewData["Module"] = new SelectList(OptionDropdown.GetModule(), "Value", "Text");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: SystemMenus/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Controller,Action,ParentId,Icon,Module,Description,FixHeader,Color,Size")] SystemMenu systemMenu)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(systemMenu);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["ParentId"] = new SelectList(_context.SystemMenus, "Id", "Name", systemMenu.ParentId);
        ViewData["Color"] = new SelectList(OptionDropdown.GetBackgroundColor(), "Value", "Text", systemMenu.Color);
        ViewData["Size"] = new SelectList(OptionDropdown.GetSize(), "Value", "Text", systemMenu.Size);
        ViewData["Module"] = new SelectList(OptionDropdown.GetModule(), "Value", "Text", systemMenu.Module);
        return View(systemMenu);
    }
```

and here my model with recursive constraint parentid

```
 public class SystemMenu
{
    public SystemMenu()
    {
        Details = new HashSet<SystemMenu>();
    }


    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]

    public SystemMenu Parent { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Module { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool FixHeader { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Size { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SystemMenu> Details { get; set; }
}
```

here's my views

```
enter code
```

```html
@model NCFramework.Models.System.SystemMenu

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Controller" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Controller" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Controller" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Action" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Action" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Action" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ParentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ParentId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ParentId">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Icon" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Icon" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Icon" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Module" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Module" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Module">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Module" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="mt-checkbox-list">
                    <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FixHeader)
                        <input asp-for="FixHeader" class="checkbox-inline" />
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Color" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Color">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Color" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Size" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Size" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Size">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Size" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

here

the example with asp.net core mvc also you can try with visual studio, these 3 files generated by scaffolding with defined model first

hoe this helps

cheers